# window.open is not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am having trouble with window.open() in javascript. I have it set up in such a way that at the click of a button certain data will be validated on the server side in php. If the data is valid, then $openView is set to true. Once the page reloads, I have the function popUP() call onload. For some reason that is unknown to me, the window.open doesn't do anything

```
    function popUp()
    {
        //if the view button was click with a valid input
        <?php if ($openView){?>
            window.open("view.php?resName=<?php echo $resumename;?>");
        <?php }?>
    }
```

I have tried it without the php statement, I have tried to echo window.open() from the server side. Nothing helped.The goal is to open the given page in a new window after the data has been validated on the server side. Any suggestions?

Comment: Calling `window.open()` on page load is a bad practice.

Comment: did you check your javascript console if any errors are being displayed?

Comment: any alternatives? How do you suggest I should tackle this problem? @Jack

Comment: debug, debug, debug... (in javascript console... :-) And, *please*, follow the advices: use AJAX to communicate with your server, do not mix serversiede and client side code like that...

Comment: no errors in the console @anurupr

Comment: Check the page source in browser: is your Javascript there, as you expect it to be?

Comment: Is your `javascript` code within `script` tag? Can you post your page source?

Comment: can you post the code that is setting the value of `$openView` as well?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

I am afraid that your **browser** does not allow such script to **prevent popups**.

---

**The solution**

You browser (and his popup blockers) will typically only allow window.open if used during the processing of a user event (like a click). So you should try to redesign your script behaviour.

---

**Maybe another interesting approach**

Maybe you should consider using a nice popup-like jquery plugin like [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). This won't be blocked by your browser, since it's not a *real* popup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the function in javascript as:

```
<script>

function popUp(resumename;)
    {

            window.open("view.php?resName="+resumename+"");

    }

</script>

<a href="javascript:popUp(<?php echo $resumename ?>)">Test</a>
```